# Vue-router4 - Passing object with <router-link :to> won't pass dynamic data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-props, vue-router4

I went through this [vue-router@4.05 object params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66864658/vue-router4-05-object-params) which is somewhat related. There is a mention of this https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/issues/494 in that thread, but I am still confused.

I am also trying to pass some data using the **:to** attribute of the *router link* component. I have made two pens to showcase the issue:

[Pen 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/router-link-props-with-route-function-and-static-prop-q24uy) passes an object that is defined within the routes definition - successfully.

[Pen 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/router-link-props-with-route-function-and-dynamic-prop-0ydic) is trying to pass a dynamic object and instead of the actual object it gets a string with [Object object] as described in the github issue.

console output:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "repository". Expected Object, got String with >value "[object Object]".
> at <Repository repository="[object Object]" onVnodeUnmounted=fn ref=Ref >
> at 
> at 
> at

So, if I get this straight, ultimately you cant pass a dynamic object cos it's parsed, but you can pass a static object?

I have tried with props: true and everything, I am trying the [function mode](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#object-mode) solution as a more complex example

snippets:

```
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'Home' }">Home</router-link>
    <router-view />
```

---

```
    <router-link
      :to="{
        name: 'Repository',
        params: { repository: { one: '1', two: '2' } },
      }">click me</router-link>
```

v1

```
    const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Home",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/repo/",
      name: "Repository",
      component: () => import("../components/Repository.vue"),
      props: (route) => {
        console.log("entered route");
        console.log(route);
        return { ...route.params, repository: { one: "1", two: "2" } };
      }
    }];
```

v2

```
    const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Home",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/repo/",
      name: "Repository",
      component: () => import("../components/Repository.vue"),
      props: (route) => {
        console.log("entered route");
        console.log(route);
        return { ...route.params };
      }
    }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing arbitrary data (not defined in route definition as [params](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)) was never supported in Vue-router and never worked as expected. Check my [answer on the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66864658/381282)

Your example `v1` works only because the value of `repository` defined in `props` function of the route overwrites the `repository` value passed from `router-link` through `params` (which is `repository: "[object Object]"` as you can see in the console)

> So, if I get this straight, ultimately you cant pass a dynamic object cos it's parsed, but you can pass a static object?

No.

1. You can't pass any object using `$router.push` or `router-link` (even it "sort of worked" in Vue-router 3 - again, see my linked answer)
2. You can define `props` on the route definition as an object or as a function returning object and it's properties will by passed to your component's props without any encoding or anything. But this is very different from using `$router.push` or `router-link` as the data does not come from source route but from router itself...

Comment: 1. I did read your answer and all the replies to that saying that it did work on vue2, which added to my confusion, to be honest.

2. I am guessing you mean the props: true syntax? 

And finally and perhaps slightly off-topic, I am guessing that implementing such a scenario (passing data from a component with router link - if that makes sense - would require vuex or some form of state management?

Comment: 1. I know, there is a lot o confusion around that topic on the internet and SO because it "sort of worked" at first sight. But all the examples breaks as soon as you use it in the real app where Back/Forward is available. 2. No I mean [props as object](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#object-mode) or [props as function](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode) (as you used it in the example)

Comment: Global state management + passing only some sort of `id` by route params is just one solution. Not only one and definitely not the best one. Other way is using `query` + some sort of serialization/deserialization of complex objects ([for example](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string)).

Answer (score 5):

## What's happening in your code:

As you can see in the warning message in the console, you are actually getting **`String`** from the prop instead of **`Object`**:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "repository".
> Expected Object, got String

Many people suggest using **Vuex** and set global states as the solution, which I believe is not what you are looking for.

### Solution

To avoid getting `[Object, Object]` as the passed data, what you can do is to stringify your object in the original page, and then parse the passed string into an object again on your targeted page.

**Original page/router component**

```vue
 <router-link
      :to="{
        name: 'Your_Route_Name',
        params: { repository: JSON.stringify({ one: '1', two: '2' }) },
      }">click me</router-link>
```

**In your targeted router component**

```vue
<template>
    <div>
        {{ JSON.parse(repository) }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ["repository"],
    setup(props) {
        //Log the parsed object in console. Example shown with Vue3 Composition API but you get the idea.
        console.log(JSON.parse(props.customer));
    }
}
</script>
```

This way, you will be able to pass Object as intented.